# Casting entire column to Spark Timestamp in Scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe `df` with the following schema:

```
ts:double
key:long
val:long
```

I want to convert the entire `ts` field to spark TimeStamp but without dropping any column. I can know how to do a select and , something line:

```
val new_df = df.select($"ts".cast(TimestampType))
```

However, `new_df` has only one column (as expected). I can do an join and be done but that's probably not a good approach. I would like to do something like

```
val new_df = df.map(udf(col("ts"))
```

that will generate a `new_df` with columns `ts` (correctly casted), key and value.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is either `withColumn`:

```
df.withColumn("ts", $"ts".cast(TimestampType))
```

or simple `select` with `*`:

```
df.select($"*", $"ts".cast(TimestampType))
```